# post [object%20Object] 404 not found angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

hi i am trying to insert a row in mi table but always obtain this problem:

> POST URL/api/presentaciones/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Well I have a form and the ng-submit="savePresentacion" inthe controller:

```
.controller('newPresentacionController', function ($scope, Presentacion, Categoria) {
             $scope.categorias ={};
             var vm = this;
             var presentacionData = {};
             $scope.savePresentacion = function() {
                 presentacionData = {
                     nombre : $scope.nombre,
                     descripcion : $scope.descripcion,
                     tipo_presentacion : $scope.tipo_presentacion,
                     usuarios_id : $scope.usuarios_id,
                     categorias_id: $scope.categorias_id,
                     longitude: self.myMarker.position.lng(),
                     latitud: self.myMarker.position.lat(),
                     zoom: 13
                 };
                 Presentacion.crearPresentacion(presentacionData).success(function (datos) {

                 });
             };
}
```

in the presentacionService have this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('presentacionService', [])
        .factory('Presentacion', function ($http) {
            var presentacionFactory = {};
            presentacionFactory.crearPresentacion = function(presenData) {
                console.log(presenData);
                return $http.post('/api/presentaciones/' + presenData);
            };
            return presentacionFactory;
        });
})();
```

after of this give the problem. I did the same with 2 tables more and dont have problem just have problem with this part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[object Object]` is how a JavaScript object is rendered by default. Your `console.log(presenData)` will similarly output `[object Object]`.

Given that you define `presenData` as a JSON object, I'm guessing you want to pass that in its entirety in your `POST`.

Change this:

```
return $http.post('/api/presentaciones/' + presenData);
```

to this:

```
return $http.post('/api/presentaciones/', presenData);
```

Note the comma. This will pass the `presenData` JSON object as the body of the request.

I would also change the logging statement to be `console.log(JSON.stringify(presenData))`, which will render the JSON representation to the console.

Comment: yeah now work thanks bro, really a don't see it. 2 days working I'm 
tired.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your presenData is an object.  When you append it to the string like this:
`'/api/presentaciones/' + presenData`

Javascript is converting the object to a string, which is represented by [object Object].

You need to determine which attribute on your presenData represents the endpoint you are trying to access.  For example, if presenData had a .id, you would want to append the string with the .id parameter.